# Issues uninstalling rvm in mac os mountain lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I tried to uninstall rvm using the rvm implode command.The problem I have are the following

`Could not remove '/usr/local/rvm/', please try removing it manually.
    Failed to completely remove /usr/local/rvm -- You will have to do so manually.`

What commands do I use to remove those directories

Answer (score 1):

try this command to remove rvm completely : `rm -rf ~/.rvm`

Also make sure to close (and re-open if needed) the terminal afterwards.

Comment: It runs but the problem is that the /usr/local/rvm , /etc/rvmrc  and ~/.rvmrc still exist.

Comment: try installing `rvm` again, it will override them.

Comment: Thanks but why do i get a permission denied when I rm -rf /etc/rvmrc

Comment: try running as `sudo rm -rf /etc/rvmrc`

Comment: did that helped you?? if so mark it as an answer so that others can also be benefited with it

Answer (score 0):

you need `sudo` for system installation implode:

```
rvmsudo rvm implode
```

or just remove it all:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/locla/rvm /etc/rvmrc /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
```

if you want to install rvm again you need to restart computer (required after system installation).